# Fullcalendar - Issue changing background color of past slots with CSS

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to change the background color of empty time slots that are in the past.
I managed to accomplish it, but Im having an issue with the **Resource Timeline View**.

**The horizontal lines separating the resources are hidden under the background.**
Note that this happens with any color, not just the one I used.

This is the css I have used :

```
td.fc-day.fc-day-past {
    background-color: #EEEEEE !important;
}
```

This is the current result :
[image: Current result]

Also, while Im here, **Is there a way to not color the whole column, but just up to the last resource ?**

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I altro tried to assign a class to the past cells through the Fullcalendar configuration (the class just assigns the bg color), but nothing changed, the issue is exactly the same :

```
 dayCellClassNames: function (arg) {
        if (arg.isPast) {
            return ['calendar-past-event-bg']
        }
    },
    slotLaneClassNames: function (arg) {
        if (arg.isPast) {
            return ['calendar-past-event-bg'];
        }
    }
```